Does anybody know of a story about how someone lowered his limitations of his knowledge?
The מזרחי says that one should train himself to admit to the limitations of his knowledge, even when he is certain that he is correct.
Does anybody have a story of a Jew / Gadol / from the Torah of somebody who admitted to the limitations of his knowledge?

I don't understand the title

Moshe admitted to having forgotten the Halacha, per Rashi to Vayikra 10:20:

וייטב בעיניו AND IT WAS PLEASING IN HIS EYES — He admitted his error
and was not ashamed to do so, by saying (instead of admitting it) “I
have not heard a statement (from God regarding this)", but rather he
said, “I have heard, but I forgot it”  (Sifra, Shemini, Chapter 2 12;
Zevachim 101b).


Good answer - but I would rather one not from the Torah - but more Rishonim / Acharonim / Modern Times!
